# store formatted text in variable python

Tags: python, string, text, string-formatting

I am trying to write a script file via a Python script

For that I have defined a function to open, write & close file
`def funcToCreateScript(filename,filecontent)`

I have another function, where I am calling `funcToCreateScript` and am trying to pass it shell script content through a variable. The problem is when I format the text as below

```
def createfile():
    var = """#!/bin/sh
             echo ${test}
          """
    funcToCreateScript(filename,var)
```

I get the output of script as -

```
#!/bin/sh
         echo ${test}
```

So, its taking the function's indentation and writing it accordingly. Is there a way to format it so that it will look like

```
#!/bin/sh
echo ${test}
```

e.g. -

```
def main():
    var = """
        #!/bin/sh
        echo ${test}
        """
    print var

main()

 > test.py

                #!/bin/sh
                echo ${test}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two solutions here, either use the new line escape character ('\n'), so it would look like:

```
def createfile():
    var = """#!/bin/sh\necho ${test}"""
    funcToCreateScript(filename,var)
```

Keep in mind, if you use this technique (which is pretty nasty solution - see below for a better alternative), and you want to see the output you'll need to `print()` (assuming Python 3.0 standards here).

Or, just simply do:

```
def createfile():
    involved. 
    var = """#!/bin/sh
echo ${test}
          """
    return funcToCreateScript(filename,var)
```

I am not sure how you got `funcToCreateScript` setup, but here is some trial code so you can see it in action (copy and paste into an interactive interpreter or new python file and run):

```
def createfile():
    var = """
#!/bin/sh
echo ${test}
          """
    return var

v = createfile()
```

If you want to get fancy, but still make it readable you can use lstrip(" ") which will remove all white space from the left side.

```
def createfile():
    var = """#!/bin/sh
             echo ${test}
          """
    script_txt = ""

    for line in var:
        script_txt += line.lstrip(" ")

    return script_txt

v = createfile()
```

Just be weary of the last solution because if you have whitespace that you intended to have there, then it'll strip that away (I personally like option 2 I listed).

Comment: how are you viewing the results?

Comment: updated the answer with some trial code for you to try out so you can see it in action.

Comment: Thanks for the input. But the change of indentation, makes the view-ability of code different.

Answer (score 3):

One way is to use [textwrap.dedent](http://docs.python.org/2/library/textwrap.html#textwrap.dedent):

> **textwrap.dedent(***text***)**
>
> Remove any common leading whitespace from every line in text.
>
> This can be used to make triple-quoted strings line up with the left edge of the display, while still presenting them in the source code in indented form.

```
import textwrap

def createfile():
    var = """\
          #!/bin/sh
          echo ${test}
          """
    var = textwrap.dedent(var)
    funcToCreateScript(filename, var)
```

Note that `\` is inserted immediately after the opening triple-quotes in order to avoid an empty line.

Answer (score 1):

If the last line of the variable consists only of spaces, and if its length is the number of spaces that should be removed from the beginning of lines of `var` other than the first, consider code like the following:

```
v = var.split('\n')
s = len(v[-1])
var = v[0]+'\n'+'\n'.join(map(lambda x: x[s:], v[1:]))
```

This strips `s` extra characters off the fronts of lines other than the first.  If some alignment is done using tabs, the above could cause problems; one might want to use string replacement rather than array slicing.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
var = """#!/bin/sh\necho ${test}"""
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option - implicit concatenation:

```
def createfile():
    var = (
        "#!/bin/sh\n"
        "echo ${test}"
    )
```

Comment: "explicit is better than implicit" (-from "import this"), but I do like this as another solution! :P  (not trolling I promise - it's just rare that I get to quote PEP 20!)